Is a New York State public school required to provide additional classes for a student who exhausts the school curriculum?
Let's say a student was to complete all of the classes in a particular subject before graduating from a New York public high school. Would said school be required to provide some way for the student to continue to take classes in that subject (online or in school)? If so what law(s) would require this? Could the school make the student pay for the classes that go beyond the standard school curriculum? If the student can be made to pay, what if they can't afford it?

In Washington state there's something known as "running start", which enables students to take college classes.  It's not handled by individual schools (maybe the school district - in my case I was able to take advantage of it as a private school student), and potentially at no cost to the student.  You may also be able to get college credits for the classes as well.  I would check if New York has a similar program.
